# UIButton touchUpInside conflicts with UITableViewCell swipe event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am displaying swipe button in `UITableViewCell` as follows :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (nullable NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *cancelAction;
    UITableViewRowAction *editAction;
    UITableViewRowAction *messageAction;
     cancelAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Cancel" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        [tableActivities setEditing:NO];
    }];
    cancelAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    editAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Edit" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        [tableActivities setEditing:NO];
    }];
    editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    messageAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"Message"  handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        [tableActivities deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }];

    return @[messageAction, cancelAction, editAction];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

In the cell's `contentView`, I have placed a `UIButton` which has a `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` `controlEvent`.
When I swipe the cell by touching the button area, both the swipe and `UIButton` event are fired.
How can I control this ?

Comment: `UITableView.canCancelContentTouches` should prevent this I think.

Comment: @Andy : Doesn't it work with the scroll ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solved your problem by checking `isEditing` property of `UITableView` in your `button` `action` like this

```
- (void)btnTap:(UIButton*) sender {
    if (!self.tableActivities.isEditing) {
        //Perform Action
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome happy coding :)